# Django Url pattern regex for tokens

Tags: django, django-urls

I need to pass tokens like `b'//x0eaa@abc.com//x00//xf0//x7f//xff//xff//xfd//x00'` in my Django Url pattern. I am not able to find matching regex for that resulting `Page not found` error.

My url will be like `/api/users/0/"b'//x0eaa@abc.com//x00//xf0//x7f//xff//xff//xfd//x00'"/`

I have tried with following regex

`url(r'^api/users/(?P<username>[\w\-]+)/(?P<paging_state>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$', views.getUserPagination),`

Answer (score 0):

Please pass the token in request header or body and then use accordingly in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Considering there are some static predictable elements in your url like -

1. api/users/
2. /" before b
3. "/ at the end after '

So I can see the url in either of the 2 ways below. Regex's mentioned accordingly:

1. `api/users/`**(set of words, digits or hyphens)**`/"`**(any character except newline)**`"/`

   **REGEX:** `^api\/users\/([\w\d\-]+)\/"(.*)"\/$`

   **URL:** `url(r'^api\/users\/([\w\d\-]+)\/"(.*)"\/$', views.getUserPagination),`
2. `api/users/`**(set of words, digits or hyphens)**`/"`**(one character-b)**`'//`**(any no. of words or digits)**`@`**(any no. of words or digits)**`.`**(any no. of words or digits)** **(any no. of words, digits, front slashes)**`'"/`

   **REGEX:** `^api\/users\/([\w\d\-]+)\/"([a-g]'\/\/[\w\d]*@[\w\d]*.[\w\d]*[\/\w\d]*')"\/$`

   **URL:** `url(r'^api\/users\/([\w\d\-]+)\/"([a-g]'\/\/[\w\d]*@[\w\d]*.[\w\d]*[\/\w\d]*')"\/$', views.getUserPagination),`

You should be able to use either of the above two. There can be multiple ways to match the token part in your url. So unless it is a big security concern, you can do with the simplest approach as mentioned in point 1.